# separate an NSString to NSString(s)

Tags: objective-c, ios

i have a string like this : `NSString *str =@"text |0|1|5|this is an other text";`
i would like to have watch component in separate string, example :

```
NSString *str1 =@"text";
NSString *str2 =@"0";
...
```

How i can do this with the complete NSString (str). thanks for your answer

Comment: possible duplicate of [split NSString into NSArray](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304450/split-nsstring-into-nsarray)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can split this data out based on the pipe delimeter.  Your result will be returned, seperated, in an `NSArray`.  You can then access the elements by index.

```
NSArray *strs = [str componentsSeparatedByString: @"|"];
```

e.g.

```
NSString *str1 = (NSString*)[strs objectAtIndex: 0];   // @"text "
NSString *str2 = (NSString*)[strs objectAtIndex: 1];   // @"0"
```

Comment: You can add as many delimiters as you want into the param string and it will check for all all of them.

Comment: @norbert, you may be thinking of `-componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:`. `-componentsSeparatedByString:` treats the string as a whole as the delimiter.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSRange range = [yourString rangeOfString:@"|"];
NSString *string1 = [yourString substringToIndex:range.location];
NSString *string2 = [yourString substringFromIndex:range.location+1];
```

You can also seperate the string like this

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, please include how/why your post will solve the problem.

Comment: hope it'll help somehow!