# One SQL Row to one UILabel

Tags: php, ios, sql, xcode, uilabel

I have almost finished my iPhone app, which revolves around social networking. I have come across an issue... Each value which is printed, friends, friend requests etc are printed onto a website, from a SQL Database, and then the iPhone reads this and renders it into a UILabel (via echo). The issue that I am having is that its ok for Jim to have Bob, Josh and John listed in his friends as one label, but when I want to view Johns profile by clicking on his name, I can't use the UILabels value because it'll be Bob, Josh and John! Is there anyway to basically get each row printed into a separate UILabel. I have tried putting some validation on the webpage for example bob!validate!josh!validate!john!validate! but I don't know how to get the iPhone to detect the !validate! and print the values inbetween in onto an individual label. I hope i'm making sense! Thanks in advance

Comment: What does this have to do with SQL?

Comment: Because all the data is stored in an SQL Database outside of the iPhone... every value is in the database

Comment: I didn't understand at all what that is about. Give us some code, otherwise no way we can help.

Comment: SQL Database - Webpage - iPhone  so the echo "$friend" from the webpage is then read on the iPhone and rendered into a UILabel, so lets say friend is bobjohnjosh, this is put into one UILabel on the iPhone. I require bob to be in one label, john to be in another and josh to be in another!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get some code to transform an NSString into a NSArray with NSStrings
   based on a separator (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6304450/split-nsstring-into-nsarray));
2. Then put each element of the NSArray into a UILabel (in the text property).